# Anydesk на эмуляторе Android

Tags: android, эмулятор, vmware

Использую VMWare для эмуляции Android 8, 9.

Установил Android на виртуальную машину, установил AnyDesk на неё, все Устройства, подключающиеся на виртуальную машину не видят его экран.

Пробовал устанавливать программы для записи экрана, они работают, НО, экран на записи немного розовый.

Помогите, пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо.

*повторил эксперимент с записью - на записи всё лагало + экран был не розовый, а синий. Пробовал делать тоже самое но с TeamViever, он при начале подключения вообще вылетал.

*при установке lineage os (без nomodeset xforcevesa), он работал. Теперь всегда при начале показа экрана в Anydesk или другом записывающей программе - экран начинает мерцать на 3-х случайных кадрах при смене изображения на экране, а на подключающемся устройстве в окне AnyDesk появляется чёрный экран такого-же разрешения + там можно же было управлять им (проверено мерцанием: если нажимать на кнопку, то экран мерцает). Приходилось перезагружать виртуальную машину, чтобы убрать мерцание.

Думаю, что можно исправить ошибку тем, что включить **акселерацию 3д графики** в настройках, но он говорит, что нужно установить драйвера (VMWare Tools), которые нельзя установить на Android x86.

Синий экран на записи исправился тем, что воспроизводил его другой плеер, но всё по прежнему лагало. Перекачивал на компьютер видео, думая, что из-за низкой производительности на виртульной машине может лагать видео, но так-же лагает.

Хочу рискнуть и установить Android x86 в качестве второй ОС. Уже заготовлена программа и отдельный диск. Хочу проверить, как будет работать Андроид на основном компьютере.